# Dataload in Google BigQuery via java client

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, user-defined-functions

I have written a BigQuery Standard SQL UDF that is doing some complex calculations and generation 45000 rows in two second. Now I have requirement to call this UDF from Java client and load this data into BigQuery.

Please let me know what is the fastest way to do this BigQuery load from java client of 45000 rows.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call your query/UDF from a Java application using the BigQuery client library?

Comment: Yes. From Java client I will call Standard SQL UDF using BigQuery client library.

Comment: Isn't this the same as what you asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055596/google-standard-sql-udf-writing-to-bigquery?

Comment: Yes this is regarding same flow Elliott. This is the second scenario that I am looking for some directions.

Comment: this one looks very much the same as your previous one. I think you should be more specific in your questions. Ideally you should show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).